# Electron React App works fine in development but not after it's been packaged

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I have built an Electron app using React. I am using Electron-prebuilt-compile in order for it to work correctly with React. Everything works perfect when I am developing and just running it with npm start. I finished version 1 and needed to package it up to be installed on other computers. I am using Electron-builder to do this with. I was able to run this smoothly with no errors. I then run the .exe that it produced and end up getting an Unexpected Token error (It was pointing at an import). It's almost as if once I packaged it up it could no longer tell what imports/exports are, which I thought is what electron-prebuilt-compiler is for. Is there something I could possibly be missing? I have followed several different guides and have also tried a different packaging script and had the same results.

Here's the my repo for the project:
[Click here for GitHub Repo](https://github.com/CaarnXLabs/HagemanConstructionInvoicing)

If you are wanting to test it out you will need to create a test firebase database. Then create a .env file exactly like below but with you firebase info. Or just throw your info directly in the app.jsx file.

```
FIREBASE_APIKEY = 
FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN = 
FIREBASE_DATABASEURL = 
FIREBASE_PROJECTID = 
FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET = 
FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID =
```

Comment: There are a million and one reasons this could be an issue.  You'd probably need to share your entire code base if you're not providing any other details.

Comment: https://github.com/CaarnXLabs/HagemanConstructionInvoicing

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in a similar situation was removing `electron` from dependencies, as strange as that sounds. You actually don't need it because `electron-prebuilt-compile` provides its own version of electron (accessible as `electron`) that works with React and ES6. That's the electron you want to use, not regular `electron`, which doesn't work with those things out of the box.

Check out the electron-prebuilt-compile documentation here, https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-prebuilt-compile, where it says "Now you can just run `electron` to run electron:"

And here are all the various "electron" dependencies in my working project (perhaps some are duplicative):

```
"electron-forge": "^5.2.2",
"electron-prebuilt-compile": "2.0.0"
"electron-compile": "^6.4.2",
"electron-rebuild": "^1.7.3",
"electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
"electron-window-state": "^4.1.1",
```

Comment: Ah guess I didn't notice that, thank you. Once I get a chance today I'll try it out.

Comment: So I removed it and even made sure to run npm uninstall on electron and it still isn't working after I build it. Still works when I run npm start but once I build it and try to install and run the built program it throws the unexpected token error.

Comment: I tried some other things and they seemed to get work but then something else broke. So first off I added a property in my build object in package.json called "electronVersion": "electron-prebuilt-compile". I did this because I found out that electron-builder did not use that by default if it was in devDependencies. This, as far as I can see fixed that issue, but now I'm getting a node-pre-gyp error from my firbase node-module. Saying cannot read property 'major' of null.